# Change the order of references display

Tags: citing, cite-package

When I reference multiple references, it shows as [1-3] while I want to [3-1]. My code as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,left=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}



\begin{document}

\cite{matignon1998stability, petravs2021novel, fractional2010}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{myrefs}\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```